# How to get content of an XML element as string?

Tags: python, xml

Considering this XML example:

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="item1">item1pre <bold>ok!</bold> item1post</item>
        <item name="item2">item2</item>
    </items>
</data>
```

I am looking for a way to get the following result:

"item1pre **ok! ** item1post"

I thought of getting all the content of item1 as a string "item1pre <'bold> ok!<'/bold> item1post" and then replace "<'bold>" and "<'/bold>" by "**", but I don't know how to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
xml="""
<data>
    <items>
        <item name="item1">item1pre<bold>ok!</bold>item1post</item>
        <item name="item2">item2</item>
    </items>
</data> 
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# python included module

def cleaned_strings_from_xml(xml_str, tag='item'):
    """
    finds all items of type tag from xml-string

    :param xml_str: valid xml structure as string
    :param tag: tag to search inside the xml
    :returns: list of all texts of 'tag'-items
    """
    strings = []
    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    for item in root.iter(tag):
        item_str = ET.tostring(item).decode('utf-8')
        item_str = item_str.replace('<bold>', ' **').replace('</bold>', ' **')
        strings.append(ET.fromstring(item_str).text)
    return strings

print(cleaned_strings_from_xml(xml))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could offload all xml processing to libxml by using an xslt transformation. Libxml is written in C which should be quicker:

```
from lxml import etree

transform = etree.XSLT(etree.XML('''
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data/items/item[@name = 'item1']">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>**</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="bold/."/>
        <xsl:text>**</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="bold/following-sibling::text()[1]"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data/items/item[@name != 'item1']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
'''))

with open("source.xml") as f:
    print(transform(etree.parse(f)))
```

In a nutshell: Match the item element with name attribute 'item1' then use relative xpath expressions to extract the strings.